# Sending a Class' attribute to an outside function in the function call

Tags: python, class, tkinter, attributes

I'm trying to generalise a function in my script by sending in the Class' attribute through the function call to an outside function, but since I have to call the attribute `self.attribute_name` inside the class and `object_name.attribute.name` outside it, I either get an error that no `self.attribute_name`exists outside the code or that no `object_name.attribute.name`exists inside. The part of my code concerned is as follows(this is just a fragment of the full code with many parts omitted):

```
class My_Window:
    self.get_info_box = Entry(root)
    self.entry_button = Button(root, text="Choose", command =lambda: self.retrieve_input(self.get_info_box, solitaire.cards))

    def retrieve_input(self, box, entity):
        self.user_input = box.get()
        entity = input_check(box)

def input_check(which_box):   # Function outside class
    my_window.which_box.delete(0, "end")    # This is want I would like to do if it worked 
    return 0   

my_window = My_Window()
```

Something in the back of my head tells me it might be possible to use lambda again to accomplish this but I'm still not sure how to use them properly and I couldn't find any active questions covering this specific case.
Anyone have any ideas how to work this out?

Comment: you need to create a minimum example that demonstrates the problem ... this does not do that .... (for example since you never call input_check of coarse its not doing anything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
def input_check(which_box):
    getattr(my_window,which_box).delete(0, "end")
    return 0

input_check("get_info_box")
```

but its hard to tell for sure

Comment: YES, that did the trick! Thank you very much and sorry for the ambigious question, I find it hard to properly formulate what I mean when I barely understand what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `my_window`.

```
def input_check(which_box):
    which_box.delete(0, "end")
    return 0
```

Incidentally, `entity = input_check(box)` won't cause `solitaire.cards` to retain the value returned by `input_check`, because assignment doesn't propagate upwards like that. If you want to change `solitaire.cards`, you'll need to do `solitaire.cards = input_check(box)` instead. If `solitaire` isn't visible inside `retrieve_input`, then you'll need to make it an attribute of `self`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that solved another problem I hadn't even begun to solve yet!